# Chartjs: How to create padding between ticks and scale label

Tags: chart.js

I'm using chartjs-node to create a graph, and I use a label for the Y-axis.

My problem is that the distance between the Y-axes ticks and label is minimal and does not look good. I've gone over the docs and couldn't find anything all that useful for this scenario... There's an option under **options -> scales -> yAxes -> ticks -> padding** but it doesn't give the desired effect.

Currently I have a workaround under **options -> scales -> yAxes -> ticks -> callback** I manually insert spaces: 
`` callback: (val) => `    ${val}%` ``

This works, but obviously is not the correct usage, and I believe that if the scale is linear this approach will prohibit me from using some of the features available with a linear scale.

Anyone knows how I can create the separation between the ticks and the label in a more elegant way?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**This can be achieved using** [**afterFit**](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/#callbacks) **callback function of y-axis :**

```
scales: {
   yAxes: [{
      afterFit: function(scale) {
         scale.width = 80 //<-- set value as you wish 
      },
      ...
   }]
}
```

**ɪɴ ᴀᴄᴛɪᴏɴ**

```js
var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
   type: 'line',
   data: {
      labels: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar'],
      datasets: [{
         label: 'LINE',
         data: [3, 2, 4],
         backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 119, 290, 0.2)',
         borderColor: 'rgba(0, 119, 290, 0.6)'
      }]
   },
   options: {
      responsive: false,
      scales: {
         yAxes: [{
            afterFit: function(scale) {
               scale.width = 80  //<-- set value as you wish 
            },
            scaleLabel: {
               display: true,
               labelString: 'y-axis label',
            }
         }]
      }
   }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.6.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="ctx" height="180"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thanks. Not quite the solution I was hoping for, still feels a bit hacky to me, but better than what I had

Comment: It's not hacky. This is the only proper way of adding scale padding.